Can't sign in, error message: fields are empty
When attempting to access Stack Overflow, I encounter warnings indicating that the username and password fields appear blank, despite being populated. The issue appears to stem from duplicate inputs for each field. The console displays an error message indicating duplicated IDs:



Interestingly, this problem is unique to stackoverflow.com; other pages such as Ask Ubuntu and Meta Stack Exchange function correctly. I have encountered the same error across multiple devices including my private PC, company PC, and mobile device over LTE.
How can I go about resolving this issue?

Same report on MSO.

Close voters: even though this happens for now only in Stack Overflow, better leave it here as well for two reasons, at least: 1) Those unable to login on SO can't report it on MSO, and 2) Signpost for other similar reports. And perhaps third reason, good chance it's going to propagate to all sites when whatever change they made will be pushed network wide. (So far few hours went by, and SE developers didn't even notice the bug)

According to Dalmarus on the Meta Stack Overflow question...

This issue has been resolved and lasted for approximately 6 hours. Just some older html that was clashing with new authentication stuff.

